# extract custom object from sandbox into scratch org (and version control system)

Tags: salesforcedx

**Issue**

How to extract custom object meta-data into my DX project since
`sfdx force:source:status` does not recognise the imported custom object via mdapi?

The reason to do this is to decouple my DX project from sandbox

**Details**

1. I have a very simple custom object with all default fields in
   sandbox.
2. I retrieved this custom object metadata from sandbox by `sfdx force:mdapi:retrieve`
3. I imported the metadata into a fresh new scratch org by `sfdx force:mdapi:deploy`
4. I validate that the custom object with all its fields is visible in scratch org
5. I run `sfdx force:source:status`, it doesn't notice this change in the corresponding scratch org

**Expected result**

`sfdx force:source:status` should have shown the diff and I would be able to pull the changes down to the local project.

Comment: This sounds like a commonplace problem, nobody has a clue or nobody had this issue at all...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured out that I need to convert the extracted meta-data from mdapi and convert into DX format in my DX project.
Scratch org will not know the difference if I directly push these meta-data via mdapi into scratch org.

```

## assume a package.xml containing list of meta-data is in place, the goal is to retrieve meta-data from sandbox and conver to a DX format so we can save these metadata to git as well as push into scratch org

sfdx force:mdapi:retrieve -r retrieveCodeoutput -k package.xml -u sandbox1

unzip retrieveCodeoutput/unpackaged.zip

## then move the unpacked folder to a DX project root path

sfdx force:mdapi:convert --rootdir unpackaged/

## above command will convert metadata info and save to current DX project

```

Comment: I tried this with an existing sandbox, but when deploying to a scratch org, all I got was the usual long list of errors (`Invalid Type`, `Variable does not exist` etc.)